# Better approach for 'Draw Fixing'

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

Recently I came across this problem [link in the comments], here is an excerpt from it,

> Siruseri happens to have some of the best chess players in India and
>   one of the most important events in the Siruseri sports calendar is
>   the Annual Chess Challenge where teams from Siruseri and Navalur
>   compete.
>
> The event is held alternately at Siruseri and Navalur. This year the
>   tournament is to be held at Sirseri and the Secretary of the Siruseri,
>   who is up for re-election this year, would like to ensure a win for
>   Siruseri. Since starting a war or accusing Navalur of possessing
>   weapons of mass destruction is beyond his scope (and he also has a few
>   more brain cells than the average leader of the free world) he decided
>   to do something clever. Draw Fixing!!
>
> To understand what he intended to do, we need to know how the Chess
>   Challege match is organised. Both Siruseri and Navalur are required to
>   send N players. Every player from both teams participates in exactly
>   one game (and so exactly N games are played). The host is expected to
>   draw lots to determine who plays who. Our secretary plans to fix this
>   draw so that the pairings are exactly as he wants them to be.
>
> Each chess player has a ELO rating indicating how good he is. The
>   higher the rating the better the player. The secretary knows the
>   rating of each of the players in the Siruseri and Navalur teams and he
>   would like to pair them up so that the number of pairs in which the
>   Siruseri player has a higher ELO rating is maximised.
>
> For example, suppose that N is 4 and the ratings of the players are as
>   below:
>
> [Table showing ELO Ratings against players](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eAxX.png)
>
> Then the secretary can arrange for Siruseri to have the higher rating
>   in 3 out of 4 games. He can do this, for example, by pairing them as
>   (1,2), (2,4), (3,3) and (4,1), where (i,j) means Player i from
>   Siruseri plays Player j from Navalur. This is the best he can do as no
>   player from Siruseri can beat Player 1 from Navalur.
>
> Your task is help the secretary to find a pairing that maximises the
>   number of pairs with higher rating for Siruseri.

So far so good , can cook up an algorithm , than tried two ways to implement that but all in vain , theoretically speaking I cant find anything wrong with this algorithm . but probably some corner cases which I am not quite aware of , can anyone have any better approach for this problem?

Here is what I have worked upon (The code in comments is the other method I was talking about),

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

bool ordering(const std::pair<int,int>first,const std::pair<int,int>second){
    return first.second > second.second;
}

int main(){
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<std::pair<int,int> >home(n);
    std::vector<std::pair<int,int> >visitors(n);// Pair for maintaining the index when they are sorted
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        std::cin >> home[i].second;
        home[i].first = i;// first one in the index , next comes the ELO rating for the player
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        std::cin >> visitors[i].second;
        visitors[i].first = i;
    }

    sort(home.begin(),home.end(),ordering);
    sort(visitors.begin(),visitors.end(),ordering);// both the teams are sorted

    /*for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        std::cout << home[i].first+1 << ' ' << visitors[i].first+1 << std::endl;
    }*/
    std::vector<int>greater(n,-1);
    std::vector<int>remaining;
    int sizeG = 0;
    int sizeR = 0;
   /* int size = 0;
    int i=0,j=0,k=n-1;  //Another process copied from a solution ,  simillar to mine one but still it doesnt works
    while(j<n){
        if(home[i].second < visitors[j].second){   
            greater[home[k].first] = visitors[j].first;
            j++;k--;
        }else{
            greater[home[i].first] = visitors[j].first;
            i++;j++;size++;
        }
    }
    std::cout << size << std::endl;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        std::cout << greater[i]+1<< std::endl;
    }*/
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(visitors[i].second < home[sizeG].second){
            //std::cout << visitors[i].second << ' ' << home[sizeG].second << ' ' << home[sizeG].first << std::endl;
            greater[home[sizeG].first] = visitors[i].first+1;
            //std::cout<< home[sizeG].first+1 << ' ' <<visitors[i].first+1 << std::endl;
            sizeG++;
        }else{
            remaining.push_back(visitors[i].first+1);
            sizeR++;
        }
    }
    std::cout << sizeG << std::endl;
    //std::cout << std::endl;
    int j=sizeR-1;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(greater[i] == -1){
            greater[i] = remaining[j];
            j--;
        }
        std::cout << greater[i] << std::endl;
    }
    /*std::cout << std::endl;
    for(int i=0;i<sizeR;i++){
        std::cout << remaining[i] << std::endl;
    }*/
    return 0;
}
```

**Note** : Unfortunately due to my reputation I cant post pictures directly and I cant also post more than a single link, sorry for that

Comment: [link for the original statement of the problem](http://opc.iarcs.org.in/index.php/problems/DRAWFIX)

Comment: [link for the testcases of the problem](http://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/contests/nov2004/Advanced-1-testdata.zip)

Comment: Does it help if you change "return first.second > second.second;" to "return first.second < second.second;" ?

Comment: Nope , I would have to change the rest of the code to accommodate that and possibly would not alter the solution

Comment: Do you ever initialize greater[i] to -1?

Comment: oops! That was a typo cause instead of commenting the first method I just deleted that and replaced by the next one and while rewriting the 2nd one I forgot about that -1